# unreported IOException ;must be declared to be thrown

Tags: java, image, exception

Im getting an error on this line:

```
private SpriteSheet spriteSheet= new SpriteSheet("Sprites/player.png");
```

I have the catch in the SpriteSheet class here:

```
public SpriteSheet(String path) throws IOException{
    BufferedImage image=null;
    try{
    image=ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(image==null){
        return;
    }
    this.path=path;
    this.width=image.getWidth();
    this.hight=image.getHeight();
    this.pixels=image.getRGB(0, 0, width, hight, null, 0, width);
}
```

Problem FIXED:
I removed the throws IOException from the constructor. Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Well what does your `SpriteSheet` constructor look like? (You've shown us a snippet, but please show the complete constructor.) Note that just printing a stack trace and then continuing as if nothing had happened is very rarely the right way of "handling" an exception.

Comment: instead of IOException use Exception , i hope it will work

Comment: @Muhammad Why would catching IOException fail to catch IOException, and catching Exception would not? That's a very bad advice.

Comment: @JBNizet Exception is the super class of all type of Exceptions it will work for any kind of exception

Comment: @Muhammad catch (IOException) does catch IOException. The problem is obviously elsewhere and catching Exception won't solve it. All it will do is catch *other* exceptions that should NOT be caught, and thus hide bugs and make them harder to diagnose. catching Exception is bad practice, and won't change anything to the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for all `Unreported XYZException; must be declared` errors is the same: there is a method that you call or an explicit `throw` for the `XYZException` exception, and there is no `catch` block around it that would cover the exception, directly or through one of its superclasses.

Note that you cannot catch an exception in an initializer expression of a *declaration*:

```
private SpriteSheet spriteSheet= new SpriteSheet("Sprites/player.png");
```

The call of `new SpriteSheet` which throws `IOException` happens in the context of your constructor, and there is no `try`/`catch` around it.

if you want to initialize with a method call that throws a checked exception, you need to supply an initialization block with curly braces, and put your initialization code there:

```
class MyClass {

    private SpriteSheet spriteSheet;

    { // Initializer block for spriteSheet
        try {
            spriteSheet=new SpriteSheet("Sprites/player.png");
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IllegalStateException("Missing a required resource", e);
        }
    }
    ... // Other declarations
}
```

Comment: I'd rather put the initialization in a constructor. And I'd rather throw a runtime exception rather than ignoring the IOException.

Comment: @JBNizet I would do that if the sprite came from anywhere except the resource. The it would indicate an error that the user could potentially process. However, the sprite comes from a resource, which is compiled into the program. If it is not there, the caller cannot fix anything: it's a build problem of `MyClass`. That is why I did not report this exception. If anything, I would assert `false` to stop program's execution.

Comment: Assertions are disabled by default. So if the exception does happen to be thrown, for whatever reason (the code might be changed later, for example), this will leave the object in an inconsistent state and make the bug hard to disgnose, instead of having a clear runtime exception saying what the problem is, and containing the IOException as the root cause.

Comment: @JBNizet You are right, I keep forgetting that assertions in Java are disabled by default (I guess I've been out of Java for too long). Thanks!